# php array print issue

Tags: php, arrays, tags

I have an array saved as a variable

```
$custgalarr=explode(",",$custgallinks);
```

If I print this like so, it shows up like this

```
$closeLink='</a>'.print_r($custgalarr);
Array ( [0] => cat [1] => dog [2] => moose )
```

I want to be able to have:

```
$closeLink='</a><a href="cat"><a href="dog"><a href="moose">'
```

But I can not get a foreach to work. How would I set $closeLink to dynamically create the  for each item that is in the array?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What code did you try with `foreach`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$closeLink = '</a>'.'<a href="'.implode('"><a href="', $custgalarr).'">';
```

Should do it.

Comment: is there a reason this would create a duplicate in safari?

Comment: my apologies, I was missing a closing tag, safari issue fixed. Thanks, this worked out perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayWalk(&$item){

return "<a href="$item"></a>";

}

$closeLink = array_walk( $closeLink , "arrayWalk");
echo "</a>" . impload("",$closeLink);
```

OR

```
$closeLink = array_walk( $closeLink , create_function("&$item",'return "<a href="$item"></a>";'));
echo "</a>" . impload("",$closeLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($custgalarr as $item) {
  echo '<a href="', htmlspecialchars($item), '">', htmlspecialchars($item), '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
$closelink = "</a>";

foreach($custgalarr as $item => $val){
        $closelink .= "<a href=\"{$val}\">";
}
```